# Extract data from mysql, constructed in repeating group style. (Convert fields into columns)

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to extract values from repeating groups:
I have table where data is distributed:

```
**tag**     **value**
tag1        value1
tag2        value2
tag3        value3
tag4        value4
```

tag and value are column names, and data is store in repeating group style, so I want my query to return

```
**tag1**  **tag2**  **tag3**  **tag4**  
value1     value2   value3    value4
```

is there a way to "convert" fields into columns?

```
substring_index(group_concat(value), ',', 1)
```

this is the closest I got, just to combine all values from column **value**, and one by one extract the values I need, but it seems very innefective

Comment: That's the way to do it. Comma is the default for GROUP_CONCAT

Comment: Issue is, if GROUP_CONCAT Returns 
'value1,value2,value3,value4'
how can I get, for example, value2 using substring_index?

substring_index(group_concat(value), ',', 2)  will return both value1 and value2

Comment: Include the value4 row too in your sample data and expected result. We didn't know it existed.

Comment: sorry for confusion, updated

Comment: How do you know how much columns do you need? are 4 values fixed? This seems to be not very logic, at least at database level

Comment: I don't know exactly how columns values I will need unfortunately... there may be values up to 10 but that it dynamic.
I agree the logic of database isn't very good, but I'm not allowed to change it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.